# How to install cgroup tools on Alpine Linux

Tags: cgroup, alpine

I need to install the control group tools on Alpine Linux; on some distros there is a `cgroup-tools` package or equivalent, but not on Alpine Linux.

I have looked for the a package containing any `cg*` file on the contents pane at `https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/`, but nothing turns up related to control groups, and searched high and low on search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is available under the typical name (`cgroup-tools`), but is only in the community repository.  Also, the package search on the web interface isn't as friendly as using the apk CLI; searching for "cgroup" doesn't turn up any results while searching explicitly for "cgroup-tools" does.

Here are the listings for the package on the community repository.
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=cgroup-tools&branch=edge&repo=community

Information on adding and using this repository can be found here:
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Repositories